# Manage different structure returned by Web Service, using Ksoap2 library in Android

Tags: android, web-services, parsing, xml-parsing, ksoap2

I'm using KSoap2 library and my web service has two possibility:

1) returns something like this

```
  -<Services> 
       -<Service> 
           <id>12</id> 
           <function_code>2</function_code>  
           <cf>AABBBCCCAAA</cf> 
           <active>0</active> <last_change_date>2012-07-12T16:00:34</last_change_date> 
        </Service> 
        -<Service> 
           <id>10</id> 
           <function_code>3</function_code>  
           <cf>ZZZZZYYYYYYKKKK</cf> 
           <active>0</active> <last_change_date>2012-08-08T16:00:34</last_change_date> 
        </Service> 
    </Services>
```

that is an array of Service object.

2) or returns this:

```
    <Msg>error: user not found</Msg>
```

in case of server side error.

Obviously I don't know what will be the web service answer; and I have implemented two different method for parsing. How can I decide what parsing method has to be used? If I create a parsing method that waits for first structure when I receive an error message I can't parse correctly.
Can I evaluate a-priori if the received message has the first or the second structure?

p.s.: I don't want use KvmSerializable class.

Answer (score 0):

How About get the XML String in View XML Like

```
public void viewXML(String xmlStr) throws IOException{
        try{
            byte[] xmlByteArray=xmlStr.getBytes();
            ByteArrayInputStream xmlStream=new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlByteArray);
            InputStreamReader xmlReader=new InputStreamReader(xmlStream);
            XmlParser parser=new XmlParser(xmlReader);
            try{
                traverse(parser,"");
            }
            catch(Exception exc){
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
            return;
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            return;
        }
    }
```

and the Traverese it Like

```
public void traverse(XmlParser parser,String indent) throws Exception{
        boolean leave=false;
        String sValue="";
        do{
            ParseEvent event=parser.read();
            ParseEvent pe;
            switch(event.getType()){
                case Xml.START_TAG:
                    if("id".equals(event.getName())){
                        pe=parser.read();
                        sValue=pe.getText()+"~~";
                    }
                    if("function_code".equals(event.getName())){
                        pe=parser.read();
                        sValue=sValue+pe.getText()+"~~";
                    }
                    if("cf".equals(event.getName())){
                        pe=parser.read();
                        sValue=sValue+pe.getText()+"~~";
                    }
                    if("active".equals(event.getName())){
                        pe=parser.read();
                        sValue=sValue+pe.getText()+"~~";
                    }
                    traverse(parser,"");
                    break;
                case Xml.END_TAG:
                    leave=true;
                    break;
                case Xml.END_DOCUMENT:
                    leave=true;
                    break;
                case Xml.TEXT:
                    break;
                case Xml.WHITESPACE:
                    break;
                default:
            }
        }while(!leave);
    }
Check This Out
```

Comment: I was using a more simple solution:

id = Integer.parseInt(pii.getProperty(0));
function_code = Integer.parseInt(pii.getProperty(1);
cf = pii.getProperty(2);

Can I evaluate If the returning SoapObject has the second structure?